# Error with multiple browserify bundles in backbone application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I want to put my vendor dependencies into another file as seen in the examples. The problem is that modules that depend on each other could not find the module they depend on. I get the error it does not find module underscore when included in an html. Here is my config:

```js
{
vendor: {
  src: [],
  dest: 'dist/vendor.js',
  options: {
    require: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.marionette', 'vis']
  }
},

dev: {
  options: {
    external: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.marionette', 'vis']
  },
  src: ["public/app/marionette_shim.js", "public/app/main.js"],
  dest: "dist/bundle.js"
}
}
```

I also made a repository for it: https://github.com/blacksonic/browsebone
After running `grunt browserify:dev` and `grunt browserify:vendor` and running `index.js` I get the error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/home/blacksonic/workspace/browsebone/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'`